# Project Euler #2 in Rust

Tags: iterator, rust, fold

I'm learning Rust, so I'm doing the Project Euler problems, as they are good exercises imho.
But I'm already stuck on the second problem. The idea is to find the sum of all the even numbers that are less than 4000000 in the Fibonacci sequence.
So I tried to do it a bit the functional way, and using a custom iterator :

```
use std::mem;
static LIMIT: uint = 4000000u;
struct Fibonacci {
    current: uint,
    next: uint,
    limit: uint,
}
fn fibo(lim: uint) -> Fibonacci {
    Fibonacci {
        current: 1u, next: 1u, limit: lim
    }
}

impl Iterator<uint> for Fibonacci {
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<uint> {
        let nex = self.current + self.next;
        let cur = mem::replace(&mut self.next, nex);
        if cur >= self.limit { return None; }
        Some(mem::replace(&mut self.current, cur))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sum = fibo(LIMIT).filter(|&x| x%2 == 0).fold(0, |sum, x| sum + x);
    println!("Sum of fibs : {}", sum);
}
```

It looks good, and it gives the correct Fibonacci sequence (I verified with `println!`s).
The problem is that it doesn't give the correct sum : it outputs `1089154` whereas it should output `4613732`. To me it seems that the fold misses the last number, but I can't see why !

I'm a total beginner with Rust, so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Have you tested your Fibonacci iterator and checked that it produced the correct sequence of number? I [tried it here](http://is.gd/ZutSp3) and the last two numbers added would produce 3524578 which is smaller than the limit... and seems like exactly what your are missing.

Comment: Thank you Matthieu, but you get the same output as I do... I added the fold and it gives me the wrong sum : you can check it [here](http://is.gd/uLKa3G)

Comment: Yes indeed, my check is just to show that the issue is neither in `filter` nor in `fold`, but in the implementation of your iterator.

Comment: Indeed, it was a stupid bug in the iterator. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

What you should be testing in your exit branch is the value of `self.current`; instead, you're testing the value of `self.next`.  In other words, you're failing to output the last number in the sequence (as Matthieu suggested).

I verified that if the iterator is implemented correctly, it should produce the correct result with this (using `grabbag_macros = "0.0.1"` as a Cargo dependency):

```
#![feature(phase)]
#[phase(plugin, link)] extern crate grabbag_macros;

static LIMIT: u64 = 4000000;

fn main() {
    let sum = recurrence![f[n]: u64 = 1, 1... f[n-1] + f[n-2]]
        .take_while(|&n| n <= LIMIT)
        .filter(|&n| n % 2 == 0)
        .fold(0, |a, b| a + b);
    println!("Sum of fibs: {}", sum);
}
```

A few other random notes: I'd avoid `uint` for this, since it's platform-dependent.  You don't need the `u` suffix unless you need to be specific about the type.  You can use `take_while` or plain old `take` instead of hard-coding a limit into your iterator.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solves my problem. It was indeed a stupid error from my part.
Thanks also for your advices and showing the use of `reccurrence!`. which I didn't know.

Comment: Good idea to recommend `take_while`, much less error-prone!